# URL Rewrite Using two $GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am currently messing around with my .htaccess file to get my URLs to look a tad cleaner.  I managed to figure it out with one variable, so I successfully changed:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?role=Top
```

into:

```
http://domain.com/lane/Top
```

and my .htaccess page to do that looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)/$ ./index.php?role=$1
```

Now what I'm trying to figure out is how to make:

```
http://domain.com/result.php?champ1=foo&champ2=bar
```

into:

```
http://domain.com/matchup/foo&bar
```

is there a way to do that in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to add another capture group to the regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)/(\w+)$ ./result.php?champ1=$1&champ2=$2
```

Would result in being able to do:

```
http://domain.com/matchup/foo/bar
```

Or specifically what you requested:

```
RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)&(\w+)$ ./result.php?champ1=$1&champ2=$2
```

Each part of the expression that is inside braces () is defined as a capture group. So this is the part that is extracted and pushed into the target string as $1, $2, etc...

Comment: This works exactly the way I want it to!  Now, the only problem is when the variable has two words with a space in it.  For example, `http://domain.com/matchup/Kha%20Zix&Ahri/Middle` I get `The requested URL /matchup/Kha Zix&Ahri/Middle was not found on this server.` Is there a way to make it so two word variables work?

Comment: If you want to match as many words as you want, you could do this sort of regular expression: ``([\w\s]+)&([\s\w]+)``

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)/$ ./index.php?role=$1

# new rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^ matchup/(\w+)&(\w+)$ ./result.php?champ1=$1&champ2=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^lane/(\w+)/?$ index.php?role=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^matchup/(\w+)&(\w+)/?$ result.php?champ1=$1&champ2=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```